# Force tabs in chrome

Tags: unity, google-chrome

I'm running ubuntu 12.04.  Chrome remembers what tabs were pinned, and re-opens them, most of the time.  Sometimes, on my computer, if the browser dies, it forgets and I have to redo them.  I have [found](http://www.addictivetips.com/internet-tips/permanently-pin-tabs-in-google-chrome/) that I should be able to force it to always open specified pinned tabs, but am unsure how to do this in unity. I have tried modifying the first exec line in /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop, but when I do, it doesn't work and it removes chrome from my side bar, until I re-add it.

I am trying to modify it like this:

```
Exec=/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome --pinned-tab-count=3 http://www.gmail.com/ http://internal.server1/ https://internal.server2/
```

Do I have my syntax wrong, or is that now how I should modify its default behavior, or both?

Answer (score 0):

Another, very different, approach to the basic problem might be to use the "[session buddy](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/edacconmaakjimmfgnblocblbcdcpbko)" extension. That way if the browser let's you down you can easily use the extension to recover your tabs.

Comment: That is an interesting one.. at least I don't have to type out the URL's if I lose my pinned tabs, I can just hit restore. Thanks!